# Can select() return ready for a socket with no data queued?

Tags: c, networking, server, posix

I am reading UNIX Network Programming by R.Stevens and the following snippet of code with relevant parts only is taken from it. It is an echo server.

```
fd_set rset, allset;
int nready, client[FD_SETSIZE];
...
for( ; ; ) {
    rset = allset;
    nready = select(maxfd + 1, &rset, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    ....
    for( i = 0; i <= maxi; i++){
        if ( (sockfd = client[i]) <= 0)
            continue;
        if (FD_ISSET(sockfd, &rset)){
            if( (n = read(sockfd, buf, MAXLINE)) == 0){
                close(sockfd);
                FD_CLEAR(sockfd, &allset);
                client[i] = -1;
            } else
                writen(sockfd, buf, n);
            ...
            }
        }
```

I'll describe briefly the variables: `client` is an array holding file descriptors assigned to connected clients; -1 represents a free entry. `nready` is the number of *fd*s ready to be read. `rset` is a structure holding bits that specifies which *fd* is ready. `allset` is a structure of the same type representing *fd*s that have to be tested by `select()`.

The inner `for` loop checks for incoming data from each connected client (this is tested through FD_ISSSET macro). If there's any pending data, the server writes it back to the client. If `read()` returns 0, that means that the client has sent a FIN to the server, so it terminates the connection with `close()`.

**Now the question**: the author says that there is a problem with the sever I just showed. Indeed, consider a malicious client that connects to the server, sends one byte of data, other than a newline, and then goes to sleep. The server will call `read()`, reading that byte, and then block in the next call to `read()`, waiting for more data from this client, thus denying service to to all other clients. I don't get why the server should block in the next call to `read()`: before the next call to `read()`, `select()` will return the ready states for each connected socket, and since our client isn't sending more data (that one byte has already been consumed), the bit for ready state of this client isn't set. Hence, the `if` block for the client isn't entered and `read()` isn't called. This is fine, unless `select()` can return ready for a socket with no data queued, which I think is impossible. So where am I wrong?

Comment: I don't see the problem, either. The description seems to assume that the server reads in a loop until it gets a newline, not the code that's shown.

Comment: Set nonblocking read from all sockets, have separate buffers/queues of buffered characters for each client and if a client sends newline - then parse the line. The best would be to have separate thread per client.

Comment: What is `writen()`? Is it some sort of non blocking `write` or is it a typo? If the latter, your code may block in the `write`. Other than that, I can't see a problem.

Comment: @JeremyP it's a modified version of standard `write` to accept at most  *n* bytes

Comment: @Barmar exactly my thoughts

Comment: @JeremyP why would it block?

Comment: @Dude If the client is blocked in its own `write`, it won't be reading bytes, so if the TCP buffers all are full, you'll get a deadlock. The correct solution is to put the bytes on a queue and put the socket in the select's write set and only write to it when the select says you can.